# Connect Macbook Pro Late 2016 with monitor DELL UP2516D

Tags: display, usb

I just received as Christmas present a Macbook Pro 15" Late 2016 with also a DELL UP2516D monitor that my friends said I should connect with the former.

The point is that I am not a computer expert as this is my first laptop and I really don't know how can I connect these two devices.

The DELL monitor comes with the following ports ([product description](http://www1.la.dell.com/vc/en/corp/peripherals/dell-up2516d-monitor/pd.aspx?refid=dell-up2516d-monitor&s=corp)):

```
DP, mDP, 2 x HDMI (MHL), 4 x USB3 with one charging port, 2 x USB3 upstream
```

and the MacBook Pro has got only the `USB-c` ports.

How do I connect my MacBook with USB-C ports to the Dell Monitor?

Comment: https://www.apple.com/thunderbolt/

Comment: Please visit the site in my previous comment, scroll way down and click on the plus below "See how to connect your devices"

Comment: so in your opinion should I buy this one http://www.apple.com/uk/shop/product/MMEL2ZM/A/thunderbolt-3-usb-c-to-thunderbolt-2-adapter?fnode=8b ?

Comment: Given that your monitor doesn't seem to have a Thunderbolt port this might not be the best option. HDMI should work much better.

Comment: You just need to go from USB-C to DisplayPort or mini DisplayPort   - this is a [good option](https://goo.gl/DcfMwu)

Comment: great! thanks guys...just bought this https://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/product/B01EXKDRAC/ref=od_aui_detailpages00?ie=UTF8&psc=1

Comment: No problem.  Go ahead and write up an answer so you can get voted up and you can select it as "the answer"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need a dongle to go from USB-C to either: HDMI, DP/mDP. At this time they're on discount from Apple since they're new, so you'll want to buy the dongle now.

Here's a full list of Apple's UCB-C dongle choices, it's a good page to review: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204360

And here is a multi-port display adapter from Apple, which provides HDMI+USB-A+USB-C, so it may be a best bet for some folks: http://www.apple.com/shop/product/MJ1K2AM/A/usb-c-digital-av-multiport-adapter